# Where it go to find the core class foundation when I compile a class

Tags: java, compilation

```
classpath:.;%JAVA_HOME%\lib\dt.jar;%JAVA_HOME%\lib\tools.jar;
```

I found the `dt.jar` and `tools.jar` is not the Java core class foundation.  Where is the Java core class foundation?

Like this

```
import java.util.Date;
public class Test {}
```

When I compile this java file, where does it go to find the `java.util.Date`?

Comment: What is the value of `JAVA_HOME`?

Comment: What? What are you trying to do and what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tools.jar` will only be supplied with a JDK (not a JRE).  I'd never heard of `dt.jar` before today, but a quick check suggests it is also an archive that is exclusive to the JDK.

`JAVA_HOME` will typically point to a JRE, not a JDK.

---

In general, I find it much easier to use a build tool for these types of things.  I use Ant.

---

Now that I notice your edit.  There should be no cause to add anything to the class-path in order to compile code that uses core J2SE APIs.  `java.util.Date` is part of the J2SE.

But specifically to answer your question.  It is located in the `rt.jar` of the JRE.

Comment: 'JAVA_HOME will typically point to a JRE , not a JDK' ? But conventionally I used to set JAVA_HOME as the jdk folder and JRE_HOME as the jre folder.

Comment: @TusarDas What you conventionally (or otherwise) do is not necessarily 'typical', so I fail to see the point of your comment.

Comment: What do you mean by 'typical' ? If I dont set JAVA_HOME in environment variables, is it by default set with any value ?

Answer (score 1):

The Java core runtime classes are found in "rt.jar" if you are using a Oracle / Sun Java SE release.

If that doesn't answer your question, you need to explain what you mean by "the java core class foundation", and / or tell us the names of the classes that you can't find.